# Writing Chemical Reaction?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I want to show the reaction between Sodium benzoate and soda lime to give benzene and na2co3

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

\def\benzene{\chemfig{**6(------)}}
\def\upsidebenzene{\chemfig{[2]**6(------)}}
\def\sodiumbenzoate{\chemfig{[2]**6(-(-COONa)-----)}}
\def\NaOH{\chemfig{NaOH}}
\def\CaO{\chemfig{CaO}}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
       \sodiumbenzoate 
       + 
       \NaOH
       \arrow{->[\footnotesize\chemfig{CaO}][$\Delta$]}
       \benzene +  \CaO
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

the main problem is there is no space between + and CaO (at reactant side) 
and i couldn't find any idea to write names below the symbol . I mean i don't know how to write sodium benzoate below its structure . And CaO and Na2C03 don't align in center with respect to benzene ring

Can someone please give me code to fix it 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! `chemfig` has `\chemname{<structure>}{<name>}`. As for the »+« problem: either put `\arrow{0}[,0]` after `\sodiumbenzoate` or define the structure differently: `\newcommand*\sodiumbenzoate{\chemfig{COONa-[4]**6(------)}}` (remember that the *first* atom in a `chemfig` structure determines its baseline!)

Comment: My comment above corresponds to your question before the edit... but the solution is the same for the updated question: put `\arrow{0}[,0]` to reset the baseline in order to achieve centered alignment or define the structures differently to give them another baseline.

Comment: @clemens and what about centering the NaOH with respect to benzene ? Can you give me code from /begin document?

Comment: As I said: put `\arrow{0}[,0]` after benzene to center following input with respect to benzene

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A name can be put below a molecule with `\chemname{<molecule>}{<name>}`.

In a scheme everything between different `\arrow`s is consideres as *one* compound and the arrow is centered to the whole structure. This can be made visible with `\schemedebug{true}`:

[image]

So one possibility is to put invisible arrows of zero length (`\arrow{0}[,0]`) in between:

```
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
  \sodiumbenzoate \arrow{0}[,0]
  + 
  \NaOH
  \arrow{->[\footnotesize\chemfig{CaO}][$\Delta$]}
  \benzene \arrow{0}[,0] + \CaO
\schemestop
```

[image]

In combination this would give (note that I use a different possibility to draw sodium benzoate in order to give it a different baseline (page 4 of the `chemfig` manual: »ChemFig always places the first atom of the molecule on the baseline of the preceding code.«)):

```
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
  \chemname{\chemfig{COONa-[4]**6(------)}}{sodium benzoate}
  \+
  NaOH
  \arrow{->[\footnotesize\chemfig{CaO}][$\Delta$]}
  \chemfig{**6(------)}
  \arrow{0}[,0]
  \+
  CaO
\schemestop
```

[image]

The name disturbs alignment again. Now you can either not use `\chemname` but put the name below with more invisible arrows or you can adjust the anchor where the `\arrow` starts (have a look at the `(.{4.85}--)` argument of `\arrow` and study section »Anchoring« in part »reaction schemes« of the `chemfig` manual):

```
\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
  \chemname{\chemfig{COONa-[4]**6(------)}}{sodium benzoate}
  \+
  NaOH
  \arrow(.{4.85}--){->[\footnotesize\chemfig{CaO}][$\Delta$]}
  \chemfig{**6(------)}
  \arrow{0}[,0]
  \+
  CaO
\schemestop
```

There may be other solutions, too. I always tend to forget one or more ways…

[image]